# Promises and setTimeout is not working together

Tags: javascript, settimeout, es6-promise

I have been struggling with this. I have a testimonial slider. nothing fancy but I want to add a transitioning class to the element for 2 seconds then remove it.

Also, I'm using this kind of projects to push myself harder. So I'm trying to do it with Promises, and testimonials are coming from Fetch call.

For some reason, `setTimeout` is not working at all. Debugger says it is resolved without going inside of the timer.

```
     arrows.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click',() => {
            return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
                container.classList.add('transition');
                setTimeout(() => {      
                    if (item.getAttribute('data-direction') == 'right'){
                        if(counter < array.length -1) {
                            counter ++;
                        } else {
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(counter > 0) {
                            counter --;
                        } else {
                            counter = array.length -1;
                        }
                    }
                }, 5000)                
            }).then(resolve =>{
                testi(array,counter);
                container.classList.remove('transition');
            })
        });
    })
```

Comment: The parameter `resolve` and `reject` exists for a reason, you have to make use of at least one of them.

Comment: Why do you `return` a promise from the `click` handler function? It will ignore it. Instead, make sure to `.catch(console.error)` errors in the end.

Comment: FYI, the whole use of a `setTimeout()` here is sub-optimal.  If you're waiting for some CSS transition to finish, you should just use the `transitionend` event and not a timer and directly monitor the end of the transition, not use your own timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
                container.classList.add('transition');
                setTimeout(() => {      
                    if (item.getAttribute('data-direction') == 'right'){
                        if(counter < array.length -1) {
                            counter ++;
                        } else {
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(counter > 0) {
                            counter --;
                        } else {
                            counter = array.length -1;
                        }
                    }
                }, 5000)   
              })
```

You are not resolving or rejecting the promise. Therefore the promise always remains in a pending state and your `then()` (or `catch()` in case of an error) method callback will never be executed.

Here is an example:

```js
let prom = new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    
    resolve('succes!')
    
  }, 5000)
});

prom.then((res) => {console.log(res); });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `resolve()` in the `setTimeout()`.

```
  arrows.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click',() => {
            // no point in returning to an event listener
           new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
                container.classList.add('transition');
                setTimeout(() => {      
                  /// do synchronous stuff

                  // then reolve promise
                  resolve()// include any value you want passed to next `then()`
                }, 5000)                
            }).then(resolve =>{
                testi(array,counter);
                container.classList.remove('transition');
            })
        });
    })
```